# Passing xcom of SimpleHttpOperator to DatabricksSubmitRunOperator

Tags: airflow, databricks

I have airflow DAG which consists of the following steps:

1. `SimpleHttpOperator`
2. `DatabricksSubmitRunOperator`

The `SimpleHttpOperator` connects to an API and gets the response. I want to then pass the response to the `DatabricksSubmitRunOperator` which can then send the response to Databricks.

How can I pull the response from the `SimpleHttpOperator` and pass it to  `DatabricksSubmitRunOperator`?

Answer (score 0):

Try the below

```py
sho_task = SimpleHttpOperator(
        task_id="sho_task_id",
        method="GET",
        endpoint="/some/endpoint",
        http_conn_id="connection_id", # Must be configured in Airflow UI under connections as HTTP connection type
        response_filter=lambda response: response.json()["nested"]["property"],
        do_xcom_push=True, # Important parameter!
        dag=dag
    )

dsro_task = DatabricksSubmitRunOperator(
        task_id='databricks_task',
        notebook_task={
            'notebook_path':'/some/notebook/path',
            'base_parameters': {'return_from_prev_task': "{{ ti.xcom_pull('sho_task_id') }}"}
        },
        dag=dag
    )
sho_task >> dsro_task
```

There are 2 things to note here. First, you need to set `do_xcom_push=True` in order to save the response to XCOM. Second, the `SimpleHttpOperator` stores the response as text(string) by default. If you need to access a certain nested property you need to set `response_filter=lambda response:response.json()["nested"]["property"]` or set `response_filter=lambda response:response.json()` then use `{{ ti.xcom_pull('sho_task_id')["nested"]["property"] }}` in `DatabricksSubmitRunOperator`